# Nested attributes not being associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, attributes

I am having some unexpected behaviour with nested attributes in that the nested attributes are saving only the default values defined in the model. I have read a lot of documentation and tried many configurations of the build_ method prefixes in the controller, but this is the best I have come up with so far. Seem like the data is being persisted to the DB, however only the default values, so I suspect the issue lies with the form or the build method in controller.
I thought the foreign keys were possibly wrong, although I think that's not the issue any more.
Newish to rails (please forgive). I have read many questions and answers on related issues, but none have done the trick. Thanks for any tips and pointers.

I have 3 models, user, year and months. All belonging to each other in the following fashion:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
   :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :years, dependent: :destroy
end

class Year < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_one :month, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :year

  validates :year, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :month
end

class Month < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :year, inverse_of: :month
  attribute :january, :integer, default: 110
  attribute :febuary, :integer, default: 0
  ....etc
end
```

The years controller is like this

```
def new
  @year = current_user.years.build
end
def create
  @year = current_user.years.build(year_params)
...etc...
end

def year_params
    params.require(:year).permit(:year, :monthly_target, :user_id, 
      months_attributes: [:january, :febuary, :march, :april, :may, :june, :july, :august, 
      :september, :october, :november, :december])
end
```

The form is like this:

```
  <div>
      <%= form.label :year, style: "display: block" %>
      <%= form.number_field :year, min:0, in: 1990...2051 %><span><small>add a year from 1990 
       to 2050</small></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :monthly_target, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.number_field :monthly_target, min: 0, step: 25 %>
  </div>
  <%= form.fields_for :months do |month_form| %>
    <div>
      <%= month_form.label :january, style: "display: block" %>
      <%= month_form.number_field :january, min: 0, step: 25%>
    </div>

  <div>
    <%= month_form.label :febuary, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= month_form.number_field :febuary, min: 0, step: 25 %>
  </div>
```

Schema is like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_09_20_123059) do
   create_table "months", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.integer "febuary"
   t.integer "march"
   t.integer "april"
   t.integer "may"
   t.integer "june"
   t.integer "july"
   t.integer "august"
   t.integer "september"
   t.integer "october"
   t.integer "november"
   t.integer "december"
   t.integer "year_id", null: false
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   t.index ["year_id"], name: "index_months_on_year_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "email", default: "", null: false
  t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
  t.string "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end

create_table "years", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "year"
  t.integer "monthly_target"
  t.integer "user_id", null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_years_on_user_id"
end

  add_foreign_key "months", "years"
  add_foreign_key "years", "users"
end
```

ps: this is rails 7 on windows, not using WSL2 (yet...!)

edit: here are params being sent through>>

```
{"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "year"=>
  {"year"=>"2022",
   "monthly_target"=>"25",
   "months"=>{"january"=>"", "febuary"=>"", "march"=>"", "april"=>"", 
      "may"=>"", "june"=>"", "july"=>"", "august"=>"", "september"=>"", 
       "october"=>"", "november"=>"50", "december"=>""}},
 "commit"=>"Create Year"}
```

also, here is the instance for the @year variable

```
>> 

@year

=> #<Year id: nil, year: 2022, monthly_target: 25, user_id: 1, 
created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

you can see I added in the form 50 to november and the rest are empty fields. This is ok though as I opted for default values of 0 on all fields in the months model.
I must say that I have found a decent work around, which I think is in the Rails ethos. I redesigned everything to just use one model "Year" and have added methods on the "Year" model to do the things I want, keeping the controller quite empty. This seems to work well, but I am slightly frustrated that I was unable to get the association between two models to work... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post what gets passed in the params? That way we can see what is pulling through from the form and check if the resulting object is valid.
you can achieve this by whacking a 'raise' in your create action (or with other tools like pry).

Comment: @Haumer, Thanks so much for your help. I have posted an edited with the visible params . I should say that I have worked on a different approach which is using one model only, with extra methods declared inside it to do the things I wanted. This works quite well although I just have to accept that I wasn't able to use the nested attributes approach. Perhaps I misunderstood the use case for them.